# I want to hide my header for 4,5 seconds while I have one popup playing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website and want to hide the header for 4,5 seconds while a popup animation is playing, the problem is that the header loads before de animation and looks unprofesional, the url is viatgesestudiants.com
Thank  you!

Comment: Please provide some source code

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/8376184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding this to your CSS and see if it takes priority:

```
.header, .header-wrapper {
  animation: pop 2s;
}

@keyframes pop
{
  0%{transform:scale(0);}
  100%{transform:scale(0);}
}
```

Comment: Awesome. glad to have helped.

Comment: @FranciscoChávezRomero I looked at your website and I want to tell you this code is running on every page of your website, not just the home page where the animation is.  You might want to add this code to somewhere that is only on your homepage and not a global CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of CSS classes like this:

1. Make a certain class be hidden, apply that class to your element.
2. For smooth transition, specify the `transition`-property for the properties set on your hidden class.
3. On load, remove said class using `setTimeout()`.

You can even use custom attributes too, to specify the delay after which its "hidden-class" should be removed!
When doing so, make sure to use a fallback-value when the attribute is not specified.

With this, you can have multiple elements be shown after different delays, all specified in HTML.

```js
for (let el of document.querySelectorAll('.onload-hidden')) {
  setTimeout(() => el.classList.remove('onload-hidden'),
      el.getAttribute('data-delay') || 1000); // Specified delay, or fallback-delay
}
```

```css
.onload-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
div {
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Always shown</h1>
  <p>This &lt;div&gt; should always be visible.</p>
</div>
<div class="onload-hidden" data-delay="4000">
  <h1>Initially hidden - 1</h1>
  <p>This &lt;div&gt; should only be visible after a set delay!</p>
</div>
<div class="onload-hidden" data-delay="500">
  <h1>Initially hidden - 2</h1>
  <p>This &lt;div&gt; should only be visible after a set delay!</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing it:

```js
//JS

// After 4.5 seconds the function runs the code and change the CSS class

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('#header').className = "headerShow headerHide"
},4500)
```

```css
/* CSS */

body {
 background: black;
}
 .headerHide {
    display: none
  }
  .headerShow {
    display: block;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100vw;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    top: 0
  }
```

```html
 /* HTML */

<header id='header' class='headerHide'>Header</header>
```